# Blackberry: Images disappearing from custom drawListRow

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I've managed to get images into a custom drawListRow:

```
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width) {
     graphics.drawBitmap(0, (index) * listField.getRowHeight(), firstrowPostion, rowHeight, thing.image, 0, 0);
     graphics.setFont(titleFont);
     graphics.drawText(thing.title, firstrowPostion, y, (DrawStyle.LEFT | DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS | DrawStyle.TOP ),  250);
}
```

The first time though everything works perfectly but once I get to the bottom of the list and start to scroll up again, the pictures have disappeared. 
Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I've figured out the second time through this code:

```
try {
        InputStream inputStream = Connector.openInputStream(ImagePath);

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i = 0;
        while ((i = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(i);
        }

        byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();
        EncodedImage eimg = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0,
                data.length);
        Bitmap image = eimg.getBitmap();
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

        return ImageUtility.resizeBitmap(image, 70, 70);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

that `InputStream inputStream = Connector.openInputStream(ImagePath);` is throwing an IOException. I understand from [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/IOException-while-opening-a-Fileconnection/m-p/704005)
that IO will be thrown under these conditions: but I don't know which is the cause:
1.  more than one openInputStream() on single instance of fileconnection.
2.  openInputStream() on already closed fileconnection.
3. openInputStream() on a directory.

again any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it's best to just create a separate array of fully formed images and send both that and the thing array to drawlistrow, instead of trying to form and draw them as every row is drawn.